# scipy.io.wavfile.read() the stdout from FFmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, scipy, subprocess, wav

After searching for a long time, I still cannot find the solution to use `scipy.io.wavfile.read()` to read the bytes from the `stdout` of [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) 3.3.6.

Here is the example code working perfectly. However, it needs to save a converted file to disk.

```py
import subprocess
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile

command = 'ffmpeg -i in.mp3 out.wav'
subprocess.run(command)

with open('out.wav', 'rb') as wf:
    rate, signal = wavfile.read(wf)

print(rate, signal)
```

And here is the code I try to get the FFmpeg output from stdout and load it into scipy wavfile.

```py
import io
import subprocess
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile

command = 'ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -f wav -'
proc = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

rate, signal = wavfile.read(io.BytesIO(proc.stdout))

print(rate, signal)
```

Sadly, it raises a `ValueError`.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\err.py", line 8, in <module>
    rate, signal = wavfile.read(io.BytesIO(proc.stdout))
  File "C:\Users\Sean Wu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 246, in read
    raise ValueError("Unexpected end of file.")
ValueError: Unexpected end of file.
```

Are there any methods to solve this problem?

Comment: Before calling `wavfile.read()`, check the first 16 bytes of `proc.stdout`.  Does it look like the beginning of a WAV file?  E.g. does it start with 'RIFF'?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser After the testing, the proc.stdout begins with `RIFF\xff\xff\xff\xffWAVEfmt `.

Comment: Thanks.  Note that the second four bytes, interpreted as a four byte hex number, are 0xFFFFFFFF.  That is supposed to be the size of the RIFF "chunk".  I doubt your file is that big, but `wavfile.read()` uses that value, so it think the file is that big, and it ends up hitting the end of the file before it expects to.

Comment: I did some testing with ffmpeg, and I noticed that when I give ffmpeg an output file argument (e.g. `out.wav`), the chunk size bytes appear to be filled in correctly, but when I use code like yours to create the WAV file using subprocess, the chunk size bytes are all 0 (instead of all 0xFF like in your example).  I don't know why ffmpeg behaves this way, but scipy's `wavfile.read()` will not handle an incorrect value for the RIFF chunk size.

Comment: (For the record, I'm using ffmpeg version 2.2.3, a very old version!)

Comment: One more for the record: when I use ffmpeg 3.4.2 with stdout redirected as in the question, I get 0xFFFFFFFF for the RIFF chunk size, the same as the OP reported in a comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when the output of `ffmpeg` is sent to stdout, the program does not fill in the RIFF chunk size of the file header.  Instead, the four bytes where the chunk size should be are all 0xFF.  `scipy.io.wavfile.read()` expects that value to be correct, so it thinks the length of the chunk is 0xFFFFFFFF bytes.

When you give `ffmpeg` an output file to write, it correctly fills in the RIFF chunk size, so `wavfile.read()` is able to read the file in that case.

A work-around for your code is to patch the RIFF chunk size manually before the data is passed to `wavfile.read()` via an `io.BytesIO()` object.  Here's a modification of your script that does that.  Note:  I had to use `command.split()` for the first argument of `subprocess.run()`.  I'm using Python 3.5.2 on Mac OS X.  Also, my test file name is "mpthreetest.mp3".

```
import io
import subprocess
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile

command = 'ffmpeg -i mpthreetest.mp3 -f wav -'
proc = subprocess.run(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

riff_chunk_size = len(proc.stdout) - 8
# Break up the chunk size into four bytes, held in b.
q = riff_chunk_size
b = []
for i in range(4):
    q, r = divmod(q, 256)
    b.append(r)

# Replace bytes 4:8 in proc.stdout with the actual size of the RIFF chunk.
riff = proc.stdout[:4] + bytes(b) + proc.stdout[8:]

rate, signal = wavfile.read(io.BytesIO(riff))

print("rate:", rate)
print("len(signal):", len(signal))
print("signal min and max:", signal.min(), signal.max())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly on both Windows 10 (FFmpeg 3.3.6) and Ubuntu 17.10 (FFmpeg 3.3.4-2).

Comment: You can replace your breaking loop by `chunk_size = riff_chunk_size.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little', signed=True)` which is equal to  `bytes(b)`.

Comment: And `riff` is still missing the chunk for `data chunk size` with correct value.