# How to transcribe the recording for speech recognization

Tags: python, ffmpeg, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, mozilla-deepspeech

After downloading and uploading files related to the mozilla deeepspeech, I started using google colab. I am using mozilla/deepspeech for speech recognization. The code shown below is for recording my audio. After recording the audio, I want to use a function/method to transcribe the recording into text. Everything compiles, but the text does not come out correctly. Any thoughts in my code?

```
"""
To write this piece of code I took inspiration/code from a lot of places.
It was late night, so I'm not sure how much I created or just copied o.O
Here are some of the possible references:
https://blog.addpipe.com/recording-audio-in-the-browser-using-pure-html5-and-minimal-javascript/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650249
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/06/easy-audio-capture-with-the-mediarecorder-api/
https://air.ghost.io/recording-to-an-audio-file-using-html5-and-js/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49019356
"""
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode
from scipy.io.wavfile import read as wav_read
import io
import ffmpeg

AUDIO_HTML = """
<script>
var my_div = document.createElement("DIV");
var my_p = document.createElement("P");
var my_btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("Press to start recording");

my_btn.appendChild(t);
//my_p.appendChild(my_btn);
my_div.appendChild(my_btn);
document.body.appendChild(my_div);

var base64data = 0;
var reader;
var recorder, gumStream;
var recordButton = my_btn;

var handleSuccess = function(stream) {
  gumStream = stream;
  var options = {
    //bitsPerSecond: 8000, //chrome seems to ignore, always 48k
    mimeType : 'audio/webm;codecs=opus'
    //mimeType : 'audio/webm;codecs=pcm'
  };            
  //recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {            
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
    var preview = document.createElement('audio');
    preview.controls = true;
    preview.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(preview);

    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.data); 
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      base64data = reader.result;
      //console.log("Inside FileReader:" + base64data);
    }
  };
  recorder.start();
  };

recordButton.innerText = "Recording... press to stop";

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(handleSuccess);


function toggleRecording() {
  if (recorder && recorder.state == "recording") {
      recorder.stop();
      gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
      recordButton.innerText = "Saving the recording... pls wait!"
  }
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/951057
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

var data = new Promise(resolve=>{
//recordButton.addEventListener("click", toggleRecording);
recordButton.onclick = ()=>{
toggleRecording()

sleep(2000).then(() => {
  // wait 2000ms for the data to be available...
  // ideally this should use something like await...
  //console.log("Inside data:" + base64data)
  resolve(base64data.toString())

});

}
});
      
</script>
"""

def get_audio():
  display(HTML(AUDIO_HTML))
  data = eval_js("data")
  binary = b64decode(data.split(',')[1])
  
  process = (ffmpeg
    .input('pipe:0')
    .output('pipe:1', format='wav')
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stdout=True, pipe_stderr=True, quiet=True, overwrite_output=True)
  )
  output, err = process.communicate(input=binary)
  
  riff_chunk_size = len(output) - 8
  # Break up the chunk size into four bytes, held in b.
  q = riff_chunk_size
  b = []
  for i in range(4):
      q, r = divmod(q, 256)
      b.append(r)

  # Replace bytes 4:8 in proc.stdout with the actual size of the RIFF chunk.
  riff = output[:4] + bytes(b) + output[8:]

  sr, audio = wav_read(io.BytesIO(riff))

  return audio, sr

audio, sr = get_audio()
```

```
def recordingTranscribe(audio):
  data16 = np.frombuffer(audio)
  return model.stt(data16)
```

```
recordingTranscribe(audio)
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'the text does not come out correctly'? What does `print(recordingTranscribe(audio))` show?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen When I say something like "Hi", it is transcribe to something strange like "other"

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

**It is perfect!**

note-required python 3.6 or below...

---

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def takeCommand():
r=sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening...")
    audio=r.listen(source)

    try:
        statement=r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
        print(f"user said:{statement}\n")


    except Exception as e:
        #speak("Sorry, please say that again")
        print('Sorry, please say that again')
        return "None"
    return statement


if __name__=='__main__':

statement = takeCommand().lower()
        print('detecting.....')
        print(statement)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am getting errors about PyAudio. How can I install it?

Comment: @DLim use this ----pip install PyAudio